# Updating JSON key value from an array by index

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops, object

I am using Angular javascript to accomplish a task where I need to update a JSON key value from an array on click function.

I have **JSON** structure like this:-

```
$scope.jsonObj = {
    "stylesheet": {
        "attribute-set": [{
                "attribute": {
                    "_name": "text-align",
                    "__prefix": "xsl",
                    "__text": "center"
                },
                "_name": "__frontmatter",
                "__prefix": "xsl"
            },
            {
                "attribute": [{
                        "_name": "space-before",
                        "__prefix": "xsl",
                        "__text": "80mm"
                    },
                    {
                        "_name": "line-height",
                        "__prefix": "xsl",
                        "__text": "140%"
                    }
                ],
                "_name": "__frontmatter__title",
                "_use-attribute-sets": "common.title",
                "__prefix": "xsl"
            }
        ],
        "_version": "2.0",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
    }
};
```

I have an array `$scope.textvalue=["center", "80mm","150%"]` . So here I want to update the key value `__text` of the JSON according to index. Means i want to push the array details according to index of `__text` in the JSON and array.

I am doing this on button click in **controller**.

```
$scope.save = function(index) {
    $scope.textvalue[index];
    console.log($scope.textvalue);
    $scope.objIndex = $scope.jsonObj.findIndex((obj => obj.__text));
    console.log("Before update: ", $scope.jsonObj[$scope.objIndex]);
    $scope.jsonObj[$scope.objIndex].__text = ? ? ? ;
    console.log("After update: ", $scope.jsonObj[$scope.objIndex]);
}
```

I did `$scope.jsonObj[$scope.objIndex].__text = ???`; as I don't know what to do here and I have an error as **$scope.jsonObj.findIndex is not a function**

Suggest me some way to update my JSON value.

Comment: use jsonObj.stylesheet['attribute-set'] to update value

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar how will i do here `$scope.jsonObj[$scope.objIndex].__text = ? ? ? ;` I didn't get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by iterating over the `$scope.jsonObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"]` array using **[`Array.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** and updating the relevant `"__text"` properties, respectively for each `attribute` object/array.

- I used **[`Array#isArray()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)** to check if the iterated `attribute` property is an `array` or an `object`.
- I copied the `$scope.textvalue` array into `arr` and used
  **[`Array#shift()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)** to get the relevant value from the `arr` array in each iteration.

This is how should be your code:

```
const arr = $scope.textvalue.slice();
$scope.jsonObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"].forEach(function(a) {
  if (Array.isArray(a.attribute)) {
    a.attribute.forEach(att => att["__text"] = arr.shift());
  } else {
    a.attribute["__text"] = arr.shift();
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$scope= {};
$scope.jsonObj = {
  "stylesheet": {
    "attribute-set": [{
        "attribute": {
          "_name": "text-align",
          "__prefix": "xsl",
          "__text": "center"
        },
        "_name": "__frontmatter",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      },
      {
        "attribute": [{
            "_name": "space-before",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "80mm"
          },
          {
            "_name": "line-height",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "140%"
          }
        ],
        "_name": "__frontmatter__title",
        "_use-attribute-sets": "common.title",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      }
    ],
    "_version": "2.0",
    "__prefix": "xsl"
  }
};

$scope.textvalue = ["center", "80mm", "150%"];
const arr = $scope.textvalue.slice();

$scope.jsonObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"].forEach(function(a) {
  if (Array.isArray(a.attribute)) {
    a.attribute.forEach(att => att["__text"] = arr.shift());
  } else {
    a.attribute["__text"] = arr.shift();
  }
});
console.log($scope.jsonObj);
```

Comment: @tanmay Yes, I just noticed this, but it works in this case, anyway I updated the answer with a solution for this.

Comment: I am getting undefined

Comment: @WhoAmI where are you getting `undefined`, in which property? have you added the line `const arr = $scope.textvalue;` ?

Comment: Yes I have added  that , i have created a new object  `$scope.newJson =$scope.jsonObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"].forEach(function(a) { ....` and consoled

Comment: @WhoAmI No, this is wrong, you don't have to make an assignment just call `$scope.jsonObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"].forEach`, you are getting `undefined` because `forEach` doesn't return any value.Remove the `$scope.newJson=` part.

Comment: @chŝdk it might not be perfectly clear in the question but I think OP wants to update only the value on particular index and not update all the occurances of `__text`. I might be wrong though

Comment: @tanmay no no , I can change any value according to the input fields. All are in ng-repeat by index.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this. I created a function like you (except it's not in AngularJS right now, but you can very easily make it).

You pass the index to the function, it will iterate over the occurances of `__text` and figure out where to put the value.

Here's the working snippet: (see the `150%` in the last/3rd `__text` value when I pass corresponding index)

```js
let jsonObj = {
  "stylesheet": {
    "attribute-set": [{
        "attribute": {
          "_name": "text-align",
          "__prefix": "xsl",
          "__text": "center"
        },
        "_name": "__frontmatter",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      },
      {
        "attribute": [{
            "_name": "space-before",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "80mm"
          },
          {
            "_name": "line-height",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "140%"
          }
        ],
        "_name": "__frontmatter__title",
        "_use-attribute-sets": "common.title",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      }
    ],
    "_version": "2.0",
    "__prefix": "xsl"
  }
};

let textvalue = ["center", "80mm", "150%"];

let textvalueIndex = 0;

function save(index) {
  let updated = jsonObj.stylesheet['attribute-set'].reduce(function(agg, obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj.attribute)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < obj.attribute.length; i++) {
        if (textvalueIndex === index) {
          obj.attribute[i].__text = textvalue[textvalueIndex];
        }
        textvalueIndex++;
      }
    } else {
      if (textvalueIndex === index) {
        obj.attribute.__text = textvalue[textvalueIndex];
      }
      textvalueIndex++;
    }
    agg.push(obj);
    return agg;
  }, [])

  console.log(updated)
}

save(2) // third item in textvalue array will be saved on the third occurance of __text
```

Comment: Thanks Tanmay let me understand this , then I will let you know.

Comment: @WhoAmI sure, let me know if you face any issues

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that `attribute` can be either an object literal or an array of object literals. Here is a function that travels through jsonObj by comparing `__text` and return a reference to the attribute in question. If nothing is found, a new attribute is added and returned instead :

```
function getAttribute(__text) {
  var attributes = $scope.jsonObj['stylesheet']['attribute-set']; 
  for (var i=0, l=attributes.length; i<l; i++) {
    var attribute = attributes[i].attribute;
    if (attribute.length) {  //array of attributes
       for (attr in attribute) {
         if (attribute[attr].__text == __text) return attribute[attr]
       }
    } else {  //attribute literal
      if (attribute.__text == __text) return attribute
    } 
  }
  var index = attributes.push({  
    attribute: { __text: __text } 
  });
  return attributes[i].attribute
}
```

example:

```
var center = getAttribute('center');
center.NEW_VALUE = 'TEST';

var new_attr = getAttribute('new_attr');
new_attr.__prefix = 'SOMETHING';
```

Comment: Yes , true that. Isn't creating new attribute will change the structure. I might be wrong. let me try. Thanks

Comment: @WhoAmI, Yes, it will change the structure by extending `attribute-set` with a new attribute, it was perhaps not necessary, just thought there needed a fallback if the attribute (or `__text`)  couldnt' be found.

Comment: I was confused why you not want to look for `__name`, but if you want just change `__text` to `__name` everywhere.  By that you can do `var attr = getAttribute('space-before'); item.__text = '120mm';`

Comment: Thanks for the info , you are right , I must go through name to change the text.